# Can not change class with jquery and waypoints

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I have a problem that is frustrating me. My body is like so:

```
<div class='chapter'>
  <div class='side side-right'>
     <image src="./image1">
  <div>

  <div class='side side-left'>
     Chapter 1
  </div>
</div>
```

and in the javascript, I have:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".chapter").waypoint(function(e){
   if (e=="down" ) {$(this).find(".side-right").addClass("current");   console.log(e);}
   if (e=="up"   ) {$(this).find(".side-right").removeClass("current");console.log(e);}
}
);
```

However, the class does not seem to change. The console prints "up" or "down" based on how I scroll, but I do not notice the class changing.

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks for the help.

I am using jquery.js and  jquery.waypoints.js

K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not the HTML element inside the waypoint handler, it is an instance of the Waypoint class. To get at the element, use `$(this.element)`.